# Shortest code in your language to persist a string across a reboot

Tags: code-golf, stateful

#### Your Programs:

You'll write two programs (both in the same language). The storage program takes a string from STDIN and stores it somewhere *persistent* (see below) and then exits without error. The retrieval program takes no input, retrieves the string that was stored, and prints it to STDOUT.

#### Objective test of Persistence:

You should be able to run the storage program on your local machine, then power-cycle your local machine, then call the retrieval program on your local machine. You can stash the string however you want (even on the web) as long as you pass this reboot test.

#### Test Cases:

Storage then retrieval:

```
echo foo | Store
Retrieve
foo
```

Repeated Stores should overwrite (like a set() method):

```
echo foo | Store
echo bar | Store
Retrieve
bar
```

Repeated Retrieval is non-destructive (like a get() method):

```
echo foo | Store
Retrieve
foo
Retrieve
foo
```

Retrieval before any invocation of Storage:

You don't need to worry about this. Your retrieval program can assume that the storage program has been run at some point in the past.

#### Input/Output flexibility.

People have asked me to expand this from strict STDIN/STDOUT to the standard IO rules. I can't because it would introduce too many loopholes. Some standard IO options already have the input stored in a persistent way, eg "programs may take input from a file". I'd like to be more flexible than just strict STDIN and STDOUT, but without opening the floodgates.

From the standard IO rules thread I'm cherry-picking the ones that don't break the challenge:

- [Programs may take input via GUI prompts](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2459/69304) and command-line prompts if you want
- [Programs may output by displaying it on screen](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7139/69304) This includes GUI dialogs
- [Programs may take input via command-line arguments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2449/69304)
- [Programs may output to STDERR](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2451/69304) but still can't actually throw errors.

If you use an alternate it must be user-interactive. The user shouldn't have to do any other work besides piping their input to your program, typing it into a prompt your program provides, or typing input as a command-line-arg of your program. The user shouldn't have to do anything other than running your retrieve program to see the output displayed on screen or sent to STDOUT or STDERR.

#### Allowed assumptions:

- Your two programs will be run in the same directory
- Your programs have read-write permissions for that directory
- Files you create will survive the reboot (not in a temp dir)
- One trailing newline that wasn't part of the string is allowed. No other trailing whitespace

#### This is code-golf, and your score is the sum of bytes from both programs.

Comment: *You can stash the string however you want **(even on the web)*** I'm not pretty sure that this should be valid.

Comment: so just `echo $@>x` and `cat x` is valid?

Comment: Your spec doesn't mention the ability to store multiple times, but you do have an example case that does so. May we assume a clean environment for each invocation of `Store`?

Comment: @Adám I believe you can assume that no attempt by the system will be made to stop storing the string.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Why would it not be valid? Even if there is a loophole discussed on meta that doesn't prevent a challenge from specifically allowing it.

Comment: Web restrictions are usually about pulling stuff from the web as a loophole to get out of doing the work of creating that stuff. In this case, if it's on the web it's because you did the work of putting it there.

Comment: @Adám I'm not sure what you mean by clean environment. Store should be able to be called multiple times in the same session, and new Stores will simply overwrite previous ones. Only one string ever needs to be stored.

Comment: @JaredK Then you should specify so. May we return the first stored string rather than the last stored string?

Comment: The "multiple stores" example case specs that out. "foo" is stored first, then "bar" stored second. "bar" is then the expected behavior of a Retrieve. Perhaps I should have named these Get and Set. Store is slightly ambiguous because it could mean append instead of overwrite. But I'm looking for overwrite.

Comment: @JaredK Not too late to [edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/168024/edit) in order to make your question clearer.

Comment: Can the storage program modify the retrieve program?

Comment: @dylnan I just recommended against it. ;-)

Comment: @Bromind What if you set fire to your computer after running store but before running retrieve? You can do a lot of silly things to break it, I don't see the need to specify all these things.

Comment: @ovs yes, as long as it passes the example cases.

Comment: @pipe thanks for pointing that out. Example cases have been fixed

Comment: Somebody needs to write an answer for a computer with magnetic-core memory.

Comment: @Mark or the modern equivalents, microcontrollers with integrated flash/EEPROM/FeRAM/MRAM

Comment: @user71659: Or for a computer where resetting the CPU doesn't clear the RAM, *just* makes the CPU jump to an init routine at a pre-defined address.  (i.e. a normal embedded system where you have total control of the firmware.)

Comment: What about "print out that you require this string as a password at login after rebooting - and then use the string given as a password"?

Comment: The requirement to survive reboots and not just process restarts only eliminates overly elaborate solutions that involve storing things in places like shared memory or daemons.

Comment: @Kaz From what I've seen of this community so far, "overly elaborate" doesn't seem to be a common stumbling block. When it's between them and a juicy hack like that it kinda just gets them going even more.

Answer (score 89):

### zsh, 4 bytes

Store: `>f` (reads from STDIN and writes to a file called `f`)
Retrieve: `<f` (writes the contents of `f` to STDOUT)

Comment: I think we have a winner.

Comment: @Adám unless there is a token to write input to file in 1 byte :P

Comment: @FreezePhoenix There is probably none unless you write a new language now which is not allowed...

Comment: @Chromium check Z80 answer: some existing languages can write from a 0 bytes program.

Answer (score 57):

## TI-BASIC (Z80), 1 [byte](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/43319)?

Store:  (just enter the string)
Retrieve: `Ans` (byte 27)

But if that isn't valid:

## TI-BASIC (Z80), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/43319)

-1 thanks to Jakob.

Store: `Prompt Str0` (bytes DD AA 09)
Retrieve: `disp Str0` (bytes ED AA 09)

Comment: Are you sure that's 5 bytes?

Comment: `"->".length == 2`

Comment: Oh... Is this the same thing I see on my calculators.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix TI-Basic uses tokens.

Comment: Aha... much better.

Comment: Hmm...Why not take input through `Ans` and persist it in the same variable? An empty store program and just `Ans` for retrieve should work: 1 byte!

Comment: @Jakob I'm not too familiar with TI calculators. Does `Ans` persist through a power cycle?

Comment: @Adám Z80 Maybe TI-BASIC does. I'm shocked by the number of people who don't even know 68k calculators (like the TI-89T) exist!

Comment: @Arthur Yep, `Ans` persists. In fact, a lot of state persists, including (I think) all user variables, equations, and history. From the user's perspective, powered off is basically the TI calculator equivalent of a sleep state for a PC, so it doesn't disrupt much.

Comment: *whispering because I'm so tickled by your one-byte solution I don't actually want you to change it:* Your zero-byte Store doesn't 'exit'. I think a reasonable definition of a program exiting is that other programs can then be run. But if I do anything else between your 1-byte store and 1-byte retrieve, it doesn't seem like it would work. Two excellent answers though. +1. Your 6 byte solution I find no flaws with.

Comment: @JaredK I definitely agree that the 1-byte solution smells of rule abuse (even though I was the one who suggested it). However, I would say the store program exits, since other programs _can_ be run after it (though they interfere with the operation of the solution). My interpretation of your "objective test of persistence" was that the programs would be run directly before and after the power cycle. If that is incorrect, perhaps you could require the 1-byte solution to be marked noncompeting?

Comment: Does it persist if you remove the batteries? Because arguably the "power" button on the calculator is really just a sleep button that keeps the SRAM powered up. I had a TI-83 which used a second button cell so you could change the main batteries without losing everything.

Comment: @user Right, some of the older calculators use a backup battery, but newer ones like TI-83 Plus use non-volatile Flash memory.

Comment: @Adám but even for things like Ans? Because Ans changes every time you make a calculation so storing it in flash memory would quickly wear that memory out.

Comment: The only things stored in Flash memory are FlashApps, OS image, and ARCHIVE'd variables. It's been a while but I don't think there's a way to ARCHIVE something programatically.

Answer (score 24):

## Browser JS, 44 bytes

**Store**:

```
localStorage.a=prompt()
```

**Retrieve**:

```
alert(localStorage.a)
```

Comment: Will `prompt()` read from STDIN?

Comment: Does a graphical web browser have an STDIN? No. `prompt()` pops up an alert that asks for you to enter text, and returns the result.

Comment: @Dev Of course a graphical web browser have a STDIN, just like every other process. If you can't use it from a specific language is another question and if the answer is "No", then I maybe it can be used in this challenge.

Comment: @Dev The default I/O methods include [input via GUI prompt](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2459/61384) and [output via GUI display](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7139/61384). Unless OP meant to override the standard, this should be valid. I'll clarify.

Comment: I've edited the challenge to allow more IO, but I'm only expanding it to a limited subset of the default IO methods. This answer is within my subset though. I like it.

Comment: @Dev every modern browser has a developer console which I would consider as stdin and out

Comment: @EsolangingFruit I never once said `prompt()` did not count as input?

Comment: No, Armin was not being condescending

Comment: @Dev Did my comment come across as condescending? If so, I'm sorry; I did not mean it that way.

Comment: Why is this my highest voted answer...

Answer (score 20):

## POSIX shell sh/bash/... 8 bytes

store:

```
dd>f
```

get:

```
dd<f
```

Comment: Nice one, beats even `cat`...

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 46 bytes

#### store, 45 bytes:

```python
open(*'fw').write('print(%r)'%open(0).read())
```

The retrieve program is built by the store command, a file named `f`. ([1 byte for the file name](http://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12819/what-assumptions-about-the-file-system-layout-can-be-made))

Comment: Surely you can use `input()`?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl `input()` only receives up to the first newline. `open(0).read` reads *all* of STDIN

Comment: You probably posted when things were still ambiguous, but as-is this answer doesn't meet the current spec. I originally intended the STDIN/STDOUT requirement to be strict, with defaults not allowed. I've expanded it, but only to a subset of the defaults. Your retrieve program, if it doesn't use STDOUT, still needs to display the output on screen. If I allowed the full defaults, the solution for every language would be 'takes input in a file' , 'gives output in a file', zero bytes.

Comment: @JaredK I don't think you quite get how this works. The `store`-program reads the input from STDIN and then stores a Python program that prints this input in `f`. Example: STORE is called with an input of `abc`. It then writes `print('abc')` to `f`. If you now call `f` (RETRIEVE), it prints `abc` to STDOUT.

Comment: @JaredK I asked you in a comment whether it was allowed to for STORE to modify RETRIEVE.

Comment: OH! that's clever. Nicely done.

Answer (score 10):

## Batch, 16 bytes

```
COPY CON A
TYPE A
```

Answer (score 8):

## Rust, 136 bytes

### Store (84 bytes)

```rust
use std::{fs::*,io::*};
```

```rust
||{let mut v=vec![];stdin().read_to_end(&mut v);write("a",v)}
```

### Retrieve (52 bytes)

```rust
||print!("{}",std::fs::read_to_string("a").unwrap())
```

### Acknowledgments

- -1 byte thanks to [Esolanging Fruit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61384)

Comment: You can save a byte by changing the import to `use std::{io::*,fs::*}` and then using `write` instead of `std::fs::write`.

Comment: How about `write("a",String::from_iter(stdin().chars()))`?

Comment: @Bergi Nice. But `chars` triggers `error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'io'` in stable Rust.

Comment: Hm, it seems `chars()` is deprecated in favour of `String::from_utf8(stdin().bytes())`. (Also I used the nightly docs, not sure whether that's the culprit)

Comment: @Bergi I tried a few variations with `bytes()` or `chars()` but none of them were very short because the iterator item is wrapped in `io::Result`.

Answer (score 8):

## Bash, <del>12 11</del> 10 bytes

### store, <del>7 6</del> 5 bytes

<del>`cat ->f`</del> # no need for `-`, stdin is default

<del>`cat >f`</del> # no need for space, `>` separates as well

```
cat>f
```

### retrieve, 5 bytes

```
cat f
```

Comment: No need for `-` in the store program.

Comment: No need for the space between "cat" and ">", either!

Comment: You should be able to do the same as in the zsh post for writing and use ``>f``. I am not sure if ``<f`` is valid for reading, though.

Comment: @allo At least on Cygwin, `>f` works like `echo '' > f` (emptying the file if it exists, creating if it doesn't), while `<f` seems to be a no-op.

Answer (score 8):

## Powershell - 4 Bytes

Storage:

```
ac
```

(alternative also `sc`)

Retrieval

```
gc
```

Edit: I just noticed the output is not allowed any user input... so it jumps from 4 to either 6 or 8 bytes

Storage:

```
ac f
```

(alternative also `sc f`) for the 8 byte version

```
ac
```

(and specify `f` as path) for the 6 byte Version

Retrieval

```
gc f
```

Answer (score 7):

## HP 49G RPL, 48 bytes

To save: `:2: A DUP PURGE STO`, 26.5 bytes

To restore: `:2: A RCL`, 21.5 bytes

If we can leave in the backup battery, we get:

## HP 49G RPL, 0 bytes

To save: , 0 bytes

To restore: , 0 bytes, since the HP 49G leaves the stack untouched across reboots.

Comment: The zero-byte solution should work for a variety of caluclators. I'll bust out my 42s when I get home.

Comment: I think your zero-byte solution, and the others being run on calculators that reboot non-destructively, are failing to meet two parts of the question: "You will make two programs." What you've got is a single program that survives the reboot. And "Store reads from STDIN and then *exits* without error." Your program is still waiting for the user to press a key. Your program's stack and execution state are still mutable. I think that means it is still running, and hasn't exited.

Comment: @JaredK The question never stipulated that the two programs couldn't be identical. As for the exiting part: traditionally in RPL input to programs is given on the stack. That _is_ the standard input.

Comment: Would the stack survive a power cycle? Maybe a soft power-off via the calculator's buttons, but I'm guess not removing the battery. So maybe it depends what a power cycle is.

Comment: @user No, stack doesn't survive soft (ON+C) or hard reset (ON+A+F) (distinct from soft-power off, Right Shift+ON), unlike storing in port 2, which is flash memory (and survives soft and hard reset). Since the TI-BASIC answer seemed to use that definition I included the stack answer for completeness.

Comment: @JaredK accidentally submitted my comment. About exiting: the program is not waiting for user input because standard input is the stack, so the string is assumed to be already entered. A 0 length program terminates instantly. You can verify it's not running because the busy annunciator is off, and that it's not waiting for user input by the lack of a cursor. (If the program was still running on either an HP calculator or a TI, doing Shift+ON to turn the calculator off would instead interrupt the program and leave the calculator on. Since this doesn't happen, a program is not running.)

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (APLX)](https://www.dyalog.com/aplx.htm), 5 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9428/43319)

Store: `⍞⍈1`
Retrieve: `⍇1`

`⍞` get line from stdin
`⍈1` write to next available component of file number 1

`⍇1` read the <s>first</s>* last component of file number 1

[image: APLX Store session][image: APLX Retrieve session]

* Documentation says *first* but experimentation shows *last*.

Answer (score 6):

## bash, 10 bytes (non-competing)

```
touch $@
ls
```

Unix filenames [can contain](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230299/43499) any character except `NUL` and `/`, and their names can be [upto 255 bytes long](https://serverfault.com/a/9548/188067) so this will be able to store only strings up to that length (consider that a limitation of the storage medium), and that don't contain '/' in them. That's one reason this is non-competing, another is that this assumes the directory it's run on is empty (or that extraneous output from `ls` is allowed). I still wanted to post this because it just seemed a cool and non-obvious way to store information.

Another on a similar vein, which wouldn't have the same length and character limitations would be:

### <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```
mkdir -p $@
find|sed '$!d;s/..//'
```

This allows the `/` character in the string, and supports many more characters (exactly how many depends on implementation).

*(-2 bytes on this thanks to @Cows quack)*

Comment: IIRC, I believe that a group at Berkeley once created a database system back in the 1990s that stored table column data as filenames (up to 255 chars). I think the rows and tables were parent directories.

Comment: In your 35 byte answer, you can change the second statement to `s/..//`. The `$` is not required because all other lines are deleted so this can only apply to the last line, and the `^` can be dropped because the substitution is only applied on the first match.

Comment: @Cowsquack Done. Thanks for explaining why the change works, too.

Comment: You need to use `"$@"`, not `$@`, to avoid getting burned by whitespace, `*`, `?`, or `~` characters.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 56 bytes

### Store (33 bytes)

```python
open(*'aw').write(open(0).read())
```

### Retrieve (23 bytes)

```python
print(open('a').read())
```

Prints with a trailing newline.

Comment: why not `input()` instead of `open(0).read()` and omit `end=` from `print`?

Comment: @MoxieBall Not sure about why `input` wasn't used, but omitting `end=` would result in a new line being added to the end of the string (i.e., not the original string) (maybe)

Comment: @NickA It looks like a newline gets printed in the question, anyways, so I don't _think_ that should matter...

Comment: Have I gone crazy or does 23+33=56 (not 54)? Also why not  use `input()`?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Good catch. As for `input`, I assume that the string to persist may contain newlines.

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, <s>46</s> 30 bytes

<sup>*-16 bytes thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974).*</sup>

One of the first times I've tried using Japt. The JS eval can be fidgety sometimes. Uses the browser's `window.localStorage`.

### Store (16 bytes)

```
Ox`lo¯lSÈSge.P=U
```

### Retrieve (14 bytes)

```
Ox`lo¯lSÈSge.P
```

Comment: +1 for being the first to use something other than standard file IO I like it.

Comment: Welcome to Japt! :)

Comment: By the way, you can bypass `setItem` and `getItem` completely with `localStorage.key`. [Set value](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=T3hgbG+vbFPIU2dlLlA9VQ==&input=OA==), [retrieve value](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=T3hgbG+vbFPIU2dlLlA=&input=)

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks! Yours also avoids the weirder control characters.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 46 bytes

Store (26 bytes):

```
getContents>>=writeFile"t"
```

Retrieve (20 bytes):

```
readFile"t">>=putStr
```

Answer (score 3):

## C (GCC), 98 bytes

### Store (46 bytes)

Input is via first command line argument.

```c
main(c,v)char**v;{fputs(v[1],fopen("a","w"));}
```

### Retrieve (52 bytes)

```c
c,d;r(){for(d=open("a",0);read(d,&c,1);)putchar(c);}
```

### Unportability

- Requires that several pointer types fit in `int`.

### Acknowledgments

- -2 bytes thanks to [*ceilingcat*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904)
- -10 bytes thanks to [Peter Cordes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30206)

Comment: This requires a C implementation where `int` can hold a pointer, for the implicit declaration of `int fopen()` to work.  (e.g. most 32-bit systems, or use `gcc -m32` if you're on x86-64 to make a 32-bit executable.)  And BTW, I tried using Linux's `sendfile` and [`copy_file_range(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html) system calls, but they don't work to/from a TTY.

Comment: Since you're writing functions, not programs, perhaps you could justify taking the input string as a function arg allowing `fputs(fopen())`, and `read(open(),buf,-1)`.  (The question now allows a command-line arg as input.)

Comment: The Linux 'splice' function copies from a pipe to a file (and vice-versa). If stdin/out are pipes, then it will save a function call, at the expense of more parameters.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby (26 Bytes)

### Set (16 Bytes)

```
IO.write'a',gets
```

### Get (10 Bytes)

```
IO.read'a'
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB (30 Bytes)

### Set (22 Bytes)

```
a=input('','s');save a
```

Can shave off 4 bytes by changing to `input('')`, but this will require input to be in single quotes: `'input string'`

### Get (8 Bytes)

```
load a;a
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

Store: `⍞⎕NPUT⎕A 1` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9uCS/KPX/o955j/qm@gWEhgApRwVDkAwXEAellhRlppalcj3qagYpcHcFKwBJ/VcAA7B@rrT8fC5kflJiEZQPMwEA)
Retrieve: `⊃⎕NGET⎕A` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9uCS/KJXrUe@8R31T/QJCQ4CUIxdQHISDUkuKMlPLUv8/6moGSbu7gqVB2v4rgAFEd1p@PheED9OBxgUA)

`⍞` get line from stdin
`⎕NPUT` put it in a native file called
`⎕A` the uppercase alphabet
`1` and overwrite if the file exists

`⊃` the first part (the data, the next parts are encoding and line ending type) of
`⎕NGET` get the native file
`⎕A` the uppercase alphabet

Answer (score 2):

## R (27 bytes)

### store (21 bytes)

```r
x=readLines('stdin')
```

### load (6 bytes)

```r
cat(x)
```

For this to work, the first script needs to be invoked with the command line option `--save`, and the second one with `--restore` (though in interactive mode this isn’t necessary: these options are the default).

This could be shortened by 7 bytes were it not for the fact that a bug in R prevents the default argument of `readLine` from working in non-interactive mode. In interactive mode, it is *not* necessary, and the solution therefore only uses **20 bytes**.

Comment: I think it would be much more efficient to use `q` directly, with the first program being `x=scan(); q("y")` and the second either `x` or `cat(x)` depending on how strict we want to be about how strings are printed. By the usual code golf rules you must also count command line arguments, so add bytes for `--save` and `--restore` (which my formulation doesn't need)

Comment: @JDL `scan` doesn’t work for arbitrary contents, and `scan(w='character')` is longer than `readLines()`. `q` is unnecessary (but `q('y')` wouldn’t work, you have to spell it `yes`). I thought about just using `x` in the second program but this would violate the requirements, as far as I understand them.

Comment: you can use `scan(w="")`, you don't need to spell out the type, `scan` will infer it from the type of argument specified. For me, q("y") works as a save-inducing quit but perhaps that depends on your version of R, and possibly whether you are using Rstudio or not.

Comment: @JDL `scan`: Oh, neat, the documentation doesn’t mention this! Unfortunately `scan` will still perform some parsing so this won’t work with all input. Anyway, `scan('stdin',w='')` happens to be the exact same length as `readLines('stdin')`. `q`: R 3.4.4 says “Error in q("y") : unrecognized value of 'save'”.

Comment: Ah, it's an Rstudio thing — I tried it in Rstudio and separately at the terminal and it only worked in Rstudio.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, <strike>48</strike> <strike>26</strike> 23 bytes

#### Write, 20+1(-n) bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to mob*

```perl
open f,">>f";print f
```

I'm actually not certain about this one points-wise, but it meets the criteria. For past entries, only the cli options were counted, so that's what I'm going with.

#### Read, 0+2 bytes

```perl
perl -pe "" f
```

Comment: Why did you score `-ne` with 1 (it should have an `e` too), but `-pe` with 2? You could use `-E` and `say` instead of `print`.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about `-E`, I wasn't familiar with that one. As for why I didn't go with `-ne`, it is because for that one, I'm actually running from a file. So, it would look like `perl -n w.pl` If this goes against PCG community standards though, I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: No, it's fine. We add a malus for extra command line arguments, so it's fine.

Comment: `">>","f"` --> `">>f"` saves 3 char

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 204 Bytes

**Warning:** Overwrites any preferences that any java programs have stored for your username!

#### Store, 94 Bytes:

```java
interface S{static void main(String[]a){java.util.prefs.Preferences.userRoot().put("",a[0]);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxDoMwDADAr0RMidRa3fsJVEbE4AaDnLYxShwWxNtdltsu4Y73NH/MOCuVBSO54aiKytHtwrP7IWc/aOG8jhOGI10DmvIXtkJLhf6SCuVIFVql8hJRH2Br6rvuhuNjCs/zNLO3yB8)

#### Retrieve 110 Bytes:

```java
interface R{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(java.util.prefs.Preferences.userRoot().get("",""));}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYxBCsMgEAC/Ip4U2v1APxGSY@lhazZhbeMWXQMl5O3Gy8DMYSLueI/zpzVOSnnBQGY8iqJyMLvwbDbk5CbNnNbnC/0x/YvSBlIVfj2qi30BVfnbnZYCQydlSoEK1EJ5FFHnYSV11t6s9f5xnq21t8gF)

```java
java S foo
java R
foo
```

This works by taking input as an arg and storing it in the user preferences backing-store provided by [java.util.prefs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html). It overwrites the user's root node to save one byte on naming a node. If you want to test it non-deestructively, either run it from a throwaway username or change the key from "" to a node name.

Comment: Good idea! Since you're using Java 10 you can shorten these by making them lambda expressions. Also if your byte count doesn't include `z` you should remove it from the programs and the TIO. Consider putting a warning at the top of the submission instead to warn people. For sure the TIO should have your 94- and 110-byte solutions.

Comment: Thanks! I made your suggested edits. I'm not certain but I don't think lambda expressions can fulfill the custom IO rules for this question.

Comment: D'oh. You're right, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 157 Bytes

**Set, 74 Bytes:**

```cs
class P{static void Main(string[]a){System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("a",a);}}
```

**Get, 83 Bytes:**

```cs
class P{static void Main(){System.Console.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("a"));}}
```

-1 Bytes thanks to VisualMelon
-2 Bytes thanks to LiefdeWen

Comment: Remove that space after `"a",`, and I doubt this will be beaten :)

Comment: You can save another byte by using `WriteAllLines` and the second param `a`

Answer (score 2):

## Sed, 2+2 bytes:

Stores to file `f`:

```
wf
```

Reads from file `f`:

```
rf
```

[Try a demo online!](https://tio.run/##LctBCoAgEEDRfaf4EOS@A3QXUSdtoeBMuOnuRtDqrV70mudMITecR62XejoeNEWGLB9dZvCGcGw7rFy3GtbQ3AaW078YXikVmS8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 23 + 16 = 39 bytes

Simply writes STDIN to file `A`, then reads file `A`.

`store.@`:

```
$A&FileWrite!AllInput[]
```

`retrieve.@`:

```
Echo!FileRead!$A
```

### Testing

```
C:\Users\conorob\Programming\attache (master -> origin)
λ echo testing | attache store.@

C:\Users\conorob\Programming\attache (master -> origin)
λ attache retrieve.@
testing
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <strike>57</strike> <strike>53</strike> 51 bytes

**Store, 27 bytes**

```
io.open("x","w"):write(...)
```

**Retrieve, 24 bytes**

```
print(io.open"x":read())
```

Answer (score 1):

**RUBY**

**Store** *(24 bytes)*

```
File.write('a', ARGV[0])
```

**Retrieve** *(16 bytes)*

```
p File.read('a')
```

Comment: The question asks for storing input from STDIN, not the arguments

Comment: I've since edited to allow IO alternates including arguments.

Comment: `File.write'a',gets` and `p File.read'a'` are a bit shorter ;)

Answer (score 1):

## C (Unix/GNU), 23+23 = 46 bytes

### Store, <s>27</s>23 bytes

```
main(){system("dd>f");}
```

### Retrieve, <s>27</s>23 bytes

```
main(){system("dd<f");}
```

This basically wraps [jofel's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168074/63856) into a C program.

Note: The `dd` commands outputs some statistics to `stderr`, so you will see some additional output when you naively run it in the shell. However, since the challenge only says that the stored string must be presented on `stdout`, not `stderr`, I take it that it is allowed to have additional output on `stderr`... Anyway, suppressing `stderr` output is as easy as replacing `dd` with `cat`, increasing the byte counts of the two programs by one, each.

Comment: Depending on your compiler you may also be able to remove the `int` return type from `main`. In old ANSI C style `int` is the default return type.

Comment: @Jakob Ah, yes, of course. I relied conciously on the implicit declaration of `system()` and forgot about that of `main()` - ouch. Thanks for pointing that out :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <s>77</s> 67 + 25 = 92 bytes

Compiles with only a few warnings on my gcc.

**store.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(int c,char**v){fputs(v[1],fopen("f","w"));}
```

Can probably golf out the include, but I couldn't figure out how.
Segfaults if you don't pass it anything, but whatever.

Peter Cordes: -1

**read.c**

```
main(){system("cat f");}
```

Comment: `int*f=fopen` should work, i.e. lie to your compiler about the pointer type.  But only if you compile for a 32-bit system (i.e. one where `int` can hold a pointer, like `gcc -m32`, or just `gcc` on a fully 32-bit system).  You can also declare main as `main(int c,char**v)`, or maybe `int**v` because you're not dereferencing.

Comment: The `main(int c,char**v)` works. I also realized I can do `fputs(v[1],fopen("f","w")`, although it still needs stdio for some reason.

Comment: It should work if you compile a 32-bit executable.  For x86-64, the compiler will truncate the `int` return value to 32 bits, then sign-extend that as a pointer.  If the returned `FILE*` is in the low 32 bits, it would work, but that's not the case on x86-64 Linux.

Comment: If you are on a system where all pointers are equal in size (rather likely), you can avoid the include by declaring `fopen` manually. Going old school with the arguments saves some bytes too: `*fopen();main(c,v)int**v;{fputs(v[1],fopen("f","w"));}`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 26+1 + 21 = 48 bytes

Store.php:

```
<?fputs(fopen(s,w),$argn);
```

Run with `echo <input> | php -nF Store.php`.

Retrieve.php:

```
<?=fgets(fopen(s,r));
```

Run with `php -n Retrieve.php`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (Node.js), 129 bytes

#### Store, 78 bytes

`(p=process).stdin.resume().on('data',t=>require('fs').writeFile('_',t,p.exit))`

#### Retrieve, 51 bytes

`console.log(require('fs').readFileSync('_','utf8'))`

Answer (score 1):

## Batch - 11 Bytes

```
%12>f
type f
```

The input is received as a command-line argument and persists (with the error message created upon execution attempt, since CMD attempts to execute the parameter) in `f`.

---

## Batch - 7 Bytes (non-competitive)

```
'>%1
dir
```

There are a plethora of invalid characters in a file name, so this wouldn't work for some strings, but this essentially saves an arbitrary character to the filename given by the parameter. To read it, it just lists all files in the directory, including our string.

Comment: Your solution appears to output on STDOUT, which is valid. STDERR is just another option, not required. The quotes around the input don't stop it from competing. The only question is whether they should be counted in your byte count. I think not, since they aren't specific to the question. They seem like standard boilerplate for Batch to take a command line arg, which isn't so different from languages that need standard command line flags. Maybe someone else with Batch knowledge will chime in. For now leave them out of the byte count. Welcome to Code Golf! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 156 bytes

Both solutions are lambdas taking empty input and throwing `java.io.IOException`.

### Store (93 bytes)

```java
import java.nio.file.*;
```

```java
v->Files.copy(System.in,Paths.get("a"),StandardCopyOption.values()[0])
```

### Retrieve (63 bytes)

```java
import java.nio.file.*;
```

```java
v->Files.copy(Paths.get("a"),System.out)
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC (v3+), 23 + 14 = 37 bytes

Simple filesystem-based answer. Works in all known SmileBASIC environments v3.x or above. Be careful, in case you happen to have an important text file named `A`!

### Store, 23 bytes

```
LINPUT S$SAVE"TXT:A",S$
```

### Retrieve, 14 bytes

```
?LOAD("TXT:A")
```

---

## SmileBASIC (v2), 21 + 16 = 37 bytes

Adjusted to work on old SmileBASIC (Petit Computer/mkII for DSi).

### Store, 21 bytes

```
LINPUT MEM$SAVE"MEM:A
```

### Retrieve, 16 bytes

```
LOAD"MEM:A
?MEM$
```

---

I'm honestly kinda amazed both versions work out to the same total byte count.

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell | 26 bytes

### Store (store.ps1 | 24 bytes)

```
"`$s='$input'">>$profile
```

### Retrieve (retrieve.ps1 | 2 bytes)

```
$s
```

### Calling

```
Read-Host|.\store.ps1

# close powershell, reboot
# open new Powershell

.\retrieve.ps1
```

Comment: The question asks for storing input from STDIN, not the arguments

Comment: @Ferrybig How's that

Comment: Wouldn't `Read-Host >t` and `gc t` be sufficient?

Comment: my bad about arguments vs STDIN. I said STDIN in the challenge description but then showed arguments in the example cases. It's fixed now.

Comment: @JaredK So now that I have revised, this is correct now right?

Comment: I'm not a powershell guy and only have linux boxes nearby at the moment, so I can't verify, but if it's taking from STDIN then yes.

Comment: Sorry to be yanking your requirements around. People wanted more IO flexibility than just strict STDIO, so now command-line arguments are legal.

Answer (score 0):

## [Cgam](https://github.com/crides/cgam), 7 bytes

#### Store, 4 bytes

```
qSow
```

#### Retrieve, 3 bytes

```
Sog
```

Unfortunately, there is not yet a web interpreter, all you can do is download the code, build it, and run it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

## NodeJS (REPL) v10.0.0, 57 bytes

Store: `fs.writeFileSync("a",process.args)`

Read: `fs.readFileSync("a")+[]`

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 23 bytes

```
InputString[]>>"a"
```

`Put[]`, abbreviated `>>` as an infix operator, receives an expression as its left operand, then writes that expression to the filespec given in its right operand, here the file `a`. `InputString[]` interactively (graphically or textually, depending on how the kernel is being accessed) receives a string and returns that expression.  This store program is 18 bytes.

```
<<"a"
```

`Get[]`, abbreviated `<<` as a prefix operator, reads the file specified by its right argument, evaluating each expression in it, then returns the last such expression.  This retrieval program is 5 bytes.

You can use `Directory[]` to find out where the file is stored.  The representation stored in the file is quoted, so is equivalent to an expression representing a string.

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal (95+92=187)

Store:

```
program i;var f:Text; s:string;begin Assign(f,'i');Rewrite(f);Read(s);Write(f,s);Close(f);end.
```

Retrive:

```
program o;var f:Text;s:string;begin Assign(f,'i');Reset(f);Read(f,s);Write(s);Close(f);end.
```

You can omit Close(f); in retrive and shorten it a little bit, but, not in a spirit of pascal!

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 36+38=74 bytes

Two scripts that write to the file `t` in the current directory. TIO Link provided both the getter and setter in both cases

#### Setter

```vb
Input""s$
Open#1,"t","w"
?#1s$
Close#1
```

#### Getter

```vb
Open#1,"t","r"
Input#1t$
Close#1
?t$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP4f5OqrEFySX5SqEJZYlJmYlJPKxeWZV1BaoqRUrMLlX5Cap2yoo1SipKNUrsRlr2wIFHTOyS9OVTbk4gLpdUstSc6A6/2PrKFICWKSsmEJQpN9icr//yGuwSHxwSFBnn7uAA)

Answer (score 0):

### HP‑41C series, 16 B

The alpha‑register (α‑register) can store **up to 24 alphabetic characters**.
The contents of the α‑register are persistent.
You can turn the calculator off and on again, they remain there until overwritten.

```
01♦LBL "S"         5 Bytes    global label requires 4 + (length of string) Bytes
02 CLA             1 Byte     clear contents of α‑register
03 AON             1 Byte     activate alpha‑keyboard
04 PROMPT          1 Byte     display α‑register and stop program execution
05 RTN             1 Byte     `RTN` does not affect local label search
```

The `CLA` (clear alpha) command clears the contents of the α‑register.
This is necessary in case of *empty* input.
The subsequent `PROMPT` command does not change the α‑register in case there is no input at all.

The `PROMPT` displays the contents of the alpha‑register, and *stops* the program.
The user can enter a string now.
Once the `R/S` (run/stop) key is pressed (≘ end‑of‑file indicator),  program execution resumes with the command following the `PROMPT` command.

```
01♦LBL "R"         5 Bytes    "S" like "store", "R" like "retrieve"
02 AVIEW           1 Byte     select the α‑register as the current display
03 RTN             1 Byte     this is cheaper than an `END` (3 Bytes)
```

Keep in mind, if in your program further calculations follow, the `AVIEW` (alpha view) command *by itself* does not stop program execution and allow the user to read the display.
The `AVIEW` command is therefore usually paired with other commands such as `STOP`.

Note, if flag 21 (printer enable) is set, but there is no printer or the printer is off, `AVIEW` *does* in fact stop program execution (so the user has a chance to *manually* record display contents).
To resume operations press `R/S` (run/stop).

---

Note, *leading* `NULL` Bytes cannot be stored *and* retrieved to and from the α‑register.
Moreover, another implementation could use *text files*.
Text files permit storing *records* of **up to 254 alphabetic characters** each.
<sub>See also [HP‑49G RPL submission](/a/168102/94076), a different pocket calculator by the Hewlett‐Packard Company.</sub>